# Rails Google analytics from the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

Is there a way, or a gem, that can send information to Google Analytics without the page load occurring?

I have a URL shortener, that redirects to the original URL (obviously), but I would like to track who clicked it.

Is there a way to send Google Analytics the request/headers or whatever it needs, from the controller, just prior to the redirect, without them having to actually load a page?

Comment: This has been asked before.

Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503329/is-there-any-way-to-post-events-to-google-analytics-via-server-side-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the measurement protocol to do that. There may be a gem that wraps the functionality, but it's pretty basic as is. Essentially, you're just sending sending HTTP hits to the GA servers with your data in the query parameters.

Here are the docs:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/